# How to work around a compound array-contains query in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore collection called `friendships` that records what users are friends with who. Each document of this collection has an array that contains the firebase uid's of the two users who are friends with each other. For example:

```
userArray: [hXz6GBtqOuUOkQ8qGmx2Te4d0Do1, 8fx9iFSslvMkfk2eiIpjUuqZT9H2]
```

I want to find a friendship document that includes two specific user id's. I'm currently performing an `array-contains` query for one uid and then iterating through the query documents to find which document contains the other uid. However, this is racks up a lot of document reads and costs a lot of money. Firstore doesn't support compound `array-contains` queries, but I was wondering if there is a way to work around this.

For example, could I do something with making each uid it's own field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could do this by using a field for each UID.  The fields would have to contain the UIDs in a predictable order.  The easiest thing to do would be to sort the UID strings, the store the smaller in `uid1` and the larger in `uid2`.  Then your client can filter by using that same order using two equality filters.

```
    .where('uid1', '==', 'abcd')
    .where('uid2', '==', 'efgh')
```

The both the readers and the writers of this document must sort the UIDs the same way.